# Checking the contents of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am working on a Chrome extension that helps me remember my passwords for websites, and it needs to detect web pages that are used for login. Currently I do that via the jQuery call `$("input:password")`.
However, I ran into a website that has the login form inside an iframe, and attempting to call `$("iframe").contents()` resulted in an error due to cross-origin security.

Is there a way for me to reliably check the contents of an iframe? I only need to know about the existence of a password element, not to interact with it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.postMessage)

Code sample...

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

Code for receiveMessage

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event){
   if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
   return;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, window.postMessage simply sends a message to the frame, and it's up to the iframe's contents to listen for a message and handle it. How is that helpful for knowing the contents of a completely unknown iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can tell, it's literally impossible for JS code to do this.

My solution: a PHP component on my server that checks the iframes' source URLs and collects a list of ones that contain a login form.